# How to calculate $\lim_{\tau\to\infty}\frac{\exp\left({\tau\cdot\ell_i}\right)}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\exp\left({\tau\cdot\ell_k}\right)}$?

Tags: limits

For $\ell_i\in\mathbb{R},\,\forall\,i\in\{1, \ldots, n\}$, calculate the following limit:

$$\kappa_i=\lim_{\tau\to\infty}\frac{\exp\left({\tau\cdot\ell_i}\right)}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\exp\left({\tau\cdot\ell_k}\right)}$$

I know that I have to see the sign of $\ell_i$ but should I compare them to each others?

It seems like, $\forall\,i$: $\kappa_i=1$.

Comment: Make yourself known. The one who downvoted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rewrite this slightly:

\begin{eqnarray}
\kappa_i &=& \lim_{\tau\rightarrow\infty} \dfrac{\exp(\ell_i\tau)}{\sum_{k=1}^n\exp(\ell_k\tau)} \\
&=& \lim_{\tau\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\exp((\ell_k-\ell_i)\tau)} \\
&=& \lim_{\tau\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+\sum\limits_{k\neq i}\exp((\ell_k-\ell_i)\tau)}
\end{eqnarray}

If any of the $\ell_k > \ell_i$ for some $k\neq i$, then what we have is that

$$ 0 \le \kappa_i \le \lim_{\tau\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{1+\exp((\ell_k-\ell_i)\tau)}.$$

What about the case where $\ell_i \ge\ell_k$ for all $k\neq i$?

Answer (score 2):

You need to factor $\exp(\tau \ell_i)$ from the numerator and denominator, then you get

$$\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(\tau (\ell_k - \ell_i))}$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$ \lim_{\tau \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{\imath=1}^n \exp(\tau \ell_\imath)}{ \sum_{k=1}^n \exp(\tau \ell_k)} = 1$$

So we obtain

$$ \sum_{\imath=1}^n \left\{ \lim_{\tau \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\exp(\tau \ell_\imath)}{ \sum_{k=1}^n \exp(\tau \ell_k)} \right\} = 1 $$

so

$$ \lim_{\tau \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\exp(\tau \ell_\imath)}{ \sum_{k=1}^n \exp(\tau \ell_k)} \le 1 $$

Working it out

$$ \lim_{\tau \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\exp(\tau \ell_m)}{ \sum_{k=1}^n \exp(\tau \ell_k)} = \lim_{\tau \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\exp(\tau \ell_m)}{ N_\textrm{max} \exp(\tau \ell_\textrm{max})} $$

where

$$N_\textrm{max}$$

is the number of maximum  of $\{\ell_k\}$

and

$$\ell_\textrm{max}$$

is the maximum of $\{\ell_k\}$

So we obtain

$$ \lim_{\tau \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\exp(\tau \ell_m)}{ \sum_{k=1}^n \exp(\tau \ell_k)} = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
0 &\textrm{for}& \ell_\imath < \ell_\textrm{max}\\\\
\frac{1}{N_\textrm{max}} &\textrm{for}& \ell_\imath = \ell_\textrm{max}
\end{array}
\right. $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\frac{1}{\kappa_i} = \lim_{\tau \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \exp (\tau \cdot \ell_k)}{\exp (\tau\cdot \ell_i)} = \lim_{\tau\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \exp (\tau\cdot (\ell_k - \ell_i)).$$
Furthermore,
$$\lim_{\tau\to \infty} \exp (\tau\cdot\ell) = \begin{cases}
\infty & \text{if } \ell > 0; \\
1 & \text{if } \ell = 0; \\
0 & \text{if } \ell < 0.
\end{cases}
$$
I've been a bit more cavalier than I probably should have here with manipulating the limits, but that's the basic idea.